# Display price on the cursor of input range

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I find this exercise of `<input type="range">` that there is a price on a `"button"`

This is a [site](https://github.com/AmirolAhmad/bootstrap-pricing-slider) and the [original demo](http://amirolahmad.github.io/bootstrap-pricing-slider/) this is elaborate from a [slider of Jquery](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemin)

I changing it for see one input range.

This is my [exercise JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/felazoka/1/edit) .

Good but I like that the cursor is a rectangle.

---

This I know that I change the **css** with delete: `.ui-corner-all { border-radius: 20px; }` or the class specified. And add define `label{width:1 px;}` )

---

The problem is other:

When the mouse is on the cursor this display the price (on the cursor) and same when the cursor moving and when is out the cursor the price is not display.

This is a image with my scope that I want.

[image]

Comment: Is [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/Dtozk) what you want?

Comment: @Harry 

To its solution already before I got there.
  but I want the price displayed or appears when the mouse is over the rectangle and when I move it
When I'm out, the price disappears from the rectangle 
As shown on the image

Comment: You mean only when you hover on the slider you want the value to be displayed?

Comment: Now you win but miss you answer if you want points....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding the below code. You need to add `id='handle'` to your anchor tag for this to work.

```
#handle{
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em; /* Just to make the handle come out of the slider and look bigger */
  top: -0.7em; /* For positioning the slider since we increased the height */
  text-decoration: none; /* Not really required */
}
#handle label{ 
  position: relative;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-top: 8px;
  display: none; /* To hide the label value when slider is not hovered, default state */
}
#handle:hover label{ 
  display: block; /* To display the label when handle is hovered on */
  top: -35px; /* To position the label with the value in relation to the handle */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/Dtozk)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your correctly, these CSS snippets added to your code could help you.

Draw the label above the slider handle:

```
.ui-slider a label {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  top: -20px;
}
```

Make the slider recangular:

```
.ui-corner-all {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Change width of the handle:

```
.ui-slider-handle {
  width: 30px !important;
}
```

Comment: Miss the part that dissapears the price

Comment: You mean only when you hover on the slider you want the value to be displayed?